# MySQL display multiple data and pass though CURL

Tags: php, mysql, curl

I have a problem getting all row values "mobile numbers" from the database and pass though CURL to send messages to multiple recipients.

I have tried calling $row[contact_mobile] where all the data shows when i echo, but when passing though CURL the last number in the database goes though.

So I need assistance to figure out how to pass though all the mobile numbers in the database

Here is my code:

```
    $SQL = "SELECT contact_mobile FROM sms_contacts WHERE group_id = '$group'";
    $result = mysql_query($SQL);
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
    $groupsms = $row['contact_mobile'] . ",";
    }

    $url = "http://bulksms.2way.co.za:5567/eapi/submission/send_sms/2/2.0"; // URL to calc.cgi
            $fields = array(
            'site'=>'',
            'username'=>($username),
            'password'=>($password),
            'message'=>urlencode($text),
            'msisdn'=>urlencode($groupsms)

                            );
            $fields_string="?";
            //url-ify the data for the POST
            foreach($fields as $key=>$value) { $fields_string .= $key.'='.$value.'&'; }
            rtrim($fields_string,'&');

            //open connection
            $ch = curl_init();

            //set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
            curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, false);
            curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST,count($fields));
            curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$fields_string);

                            // Check if all data shows
            echo $url.$fields.$fields_string;

            //execute post
            ob_start();
            curl_exec($ch);
            ob_end_clean();
```

What i receive:

```
    http://bulksms.2way.co.za:5567/eapi/submission/send_sms/2/2.0Array?site=&username=xxxx&password=xxxx&message=the message&msisdn=44123456789%2C&
```

What it should be like

```
    http://bulksms.2way.co.za:5567/eapi/submission/send_sms/2/2.0Array?site=&username=xxxx&password=xxxx&message=the message&msisdn=44123456789,44213456789
```

Any suggestions on how to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could probably have troubleshooted your problem a little bit more before just dropping it here... You just need to replace

```
$groupsms = $row['contact_mobile'] . ",";
```

by

```
$groupsms .= $row['contact_mobile'] . ",";
          ^
```

Since right now you're assigning `$groupsms` to `$row['contact_mobile'] . ","` and thus returning the last value only.

Comment: Thanks! stupid of me to miss that, now i can get some sleep :-)